# use the same model multiple times with shared wheights in tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I'm using the encoder part of a transformer to convert a stream of word tokens (text) into a vector . this vector is then fed into a LSTM.

[image]

The graphic above illustrates the concept. My question is: how can I make sure tensorflow reuses the same model (layers, wheights, etc) for each time step.

This is how the transformer is applied:

```
Xn_ts = []

for t in range(self.T):
    xt = self.Xn[:, t, :] # shape of Xn = (None,timesteps,textlength)
    enc = self.transformer.encode(xt)
    vec = tf.expand_dims(tf.reduce_mean(enc, axis=1), axis=1)
    Xn_ts.append(vec)

XnC = tf.concat(Xn_ts, axis=1)
#XnC is then fed to a LSTM
```

The encode function looks like this:

```
def encode(self, xs, training=True):
    with tf.variable_scope("encoder", reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):

        enc = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(self.embeddings, xs)
        enc *= self.hp.d_model**0.5

        enc += positional_encoding(enc, self.hp.maxlen)
        enc = tf.layers.dropout(enc, self.hp.dropout_rate, training=training)

        for i in range(self.hp.num_blocks):
            with tf.variable_scope("num_blocks_{}".format(i), reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
                enc = multihead_attention(queries=enc,
                                          keys=enc,
                                          values=enc,
                                          num_heads=self.hp.num_heads,
                                          dropout_rate=self.hp.dropout_rate,
                                          training=training,
                                          causality=False)

                enc = ff(enc, num_units=[self.hp.d_ff, self.hp.d_model])

    memory = enc

    return memory
```

Enabling `reuse` in the encoder's scope should in theory do it, but when I increase the number of timesteps, the number of trainable parameters go up aswell, so I'm clearly missing something.

Comment: You already see that the number of trainable parameters go up. Please find out which variables are not reused. Is it embedding variables or parameters in your transformers?

Comment: @greeness was a good call. I forgot about the dense layer that joins the LSTM outputs together, which obviously grows with the amount of timesteps. Everything else remained the same.. so it should work the way I did it, right? Gradient descent too, and all?

Comment: Looks good to me.